# Cannot access state outside NativeModules after creating Native Bridge React Native

Tags: react-native, bridge

I am trying to access state outside the results received from NativeModule after creating bridge with native android. Data shows in console.log but cannot accessed outside.

```
NativeModules["GetapplistModule"].getNonSystemApps(res => {
    var pairs = [];
    for(var key in res){
      var obj = JSON.parse(res[key]);
      pairs.push(obj);
    }
    const [AppData] = React.useState(pairs);
  });

 type AppProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof AppProps>;
 export const notificationTweets: Array<AppProps> = {AppData};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `useEffect`

If you are having same problem Wrap your function in useEffect and assign state inside the scope somthing like this.

```
const [AppData, setApps] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
NativeModules["GetapplistModule"].getNonSystemApps(res => {
    var pairs = [];
    for(var key in res){
      var obj = JSON.parse(res[key]);
      pairs.push(obj);
    }
    setApps(pairs);
  });

 type AppProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof AppProps>;
 export const notificationTweets: Array<AppProps> = {AppData};
}, []);
```

Now, you can access state anywhere like

```
console.log(AppData);
```

Hope it helps to someone who is dealing with same issue.